# Can Ansible check if password is correct before running playbook?

Tags: ansible

is there any mechanism that checks if the SSH/SUDO password is correct? When deploying a playbook across the whole environment, after putting in the wrong password, ansible runs on all hosts with the wrong password, it fails and my LDAP/AD account is locked out.

Comment: No, there is no mechanism. You need to implement one yourself. Better yet, don't use passwords.

Comment: @techraf I think that'll be my next feature request. SSH keys are one thing, passwordless sudo is another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since, as it turns out, Ansible does not seem to have this functionality, I decided to create a workaround myself:
in site.yml, I added a role that only runs on one server and has 1 or optionally 2 tasks in it. The first one checks if login itself works, the second one checks if sudo works.

```
- name: Check ssh password first
  command: echo "ssh password correct"
  changed_when: false

- name: Check sudo password first
  command: echo "sudo password correct"
  become: yes
  changed_when: false
```

Answer (score 1):

As a good workaround, I usually put this in site.yml:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
   - name: site.yml | Check if Password is correct
  become: true
  command: echo "PW is correct"
  run_once: true
  tags:
    - always
```

That task will run always, no matter what tags you start the playbook with and will check if the ssh/sudo password works on one host before hammering all your servers with login requests.